# App crashes when i try to open a certain activity

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

Hi All I'm really new to Android Studio. I'm trying to build an app but it keeps crashing when i try to open a certain Activity the other activities open ok just the forth one is the problem.

```
public class ForthActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText email;
private Button Save;

DatabaseReference databaseReference;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_forth);


   email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    Save =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");


    Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AddData();

        }
    });


}

public void AddData(){
    String Email = email.getText().toString().trim();

    SaveData saveData = new SaveData(Email);

    databaseReference.push().setValue(saveData);

}
}
```

Comment: Please post some error log or something that indicates what the problem is.

Comment: Have a look here: [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173)

Comment: pls explain more or else post log